# Connecting column from one database with multiple columns from a different DB and returning an output in a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a database of `domains` (list with domains -> *example: thisisadomain.com*) in **one database** and list of `emails` and `number of clicks` in a **different database**.

I need the `domain` list (from DB 1) to go through the second database and for every match record (`Domain` finds the same `domain in the email`. *example: thisisadomain.com -> testmail@thisisadomain.com*) in the email the query also checks how many clicks there is in the same row for the matching domain=email.

Every `email` has the `number of clicks` in the same row (DB 2), there are also multiple `emails` with the same `domain` but different email address, these should be all counted as one in the end. All `numbers of clicks` have real value so for the `emails` with the same `domain` that number should be merged together to get a full number of clicks for all emails with same domain. There is only one number in the `number of clicks` that would need to be transformed from '65535' to number '1' since that is the value of **1** click. Note that database 2 can't be altered!

So the query should first find all of the `emails` that match with the `domains` from database 1. Then look up the `number of clicks` from every `email`, merge `emails` and `NumOfClicks` with the same email address into one `domain` ~ *(continues bellow example)*

*Example:*

> Searching with `domains` row. One of the `domains` is also called *domaindomain.com*. The data bellow this blockquote is stored in database 2 in `email` column and the number next to the emails is the `click count`. The query found a match from DB 1 `domain` list!

```
 +-------------------------------+--------------+
 |            Email              |  NumOfClicks |
 +-------------------------------+--------------+
 |  testmail1@domaindomain.com   |     2499     |
 +-------------------------------+--------------+
 |  testmail2@domaindomain.com   |     65535    |
 +-------------------------------+--------------+
```

*Table desc: Table from DB 2 that has Emails and NumOfClicks inside the table*

*Result:*

> The query merged together both `Emails` and `NumOfClicks` and outputted the data back in database 1. Database 1 has an empty column called `NumOfClicks` where the merged data of "clicks" should be imported. In this example the merged click count is 2500 although the numbers in the upper table are 2499 and 65535. The result down there is 2500, because **65535 is treated as NUMBER 1** and therefor it got transformed. `2499 + 1 = 2500`

```
+-------------------------------+--------------+ 
|            Domain             |  NumOfClicks |
+-------------------------------+--------------+
|       domaindomain.com        |     2500     |
+-------------------------------+--------------+
```

~ and `SUM` all of the `NumOfClicks` together and output new number back to the database 1 in the column `NumOfClicks` next to the `domain` which the data goes for.

**LEGEND**

```
DATABASE1 before the query: **TABLENAME: DomainsActiV7**

 +-------------------------------+--------------+
 |            Domain             |  NumOfClicks |
 +-------------------------------+--------------+
 |        domaindomain.com       |              |
 +-------------------------------+--------------+
 |    stackoverflowislove.com    |              |
 +-------------------------------+--------------+
 |             ...               |              |
 +-------------------------------+--------------+

DATABASE2 before the query: **TABLENAME: ActiV7**

     +-------------------------------+--------------+
     |            Email              |  NumOfClicks |
     +-------------------------------+--------------+
     |     info@domaindomain.com     |     43156    |
     +-------------------------------+--------------+
     | super@stackoverflowislove.com |      561     |
     +-------------------------------+--------------+
     |             ...               |              |
     +-------------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Please provide code that you have tried so far

Comment: Why is "65535 is treated as NUMBER 1"??? Seems to me the issue is that you need an aggregate query but you don't know how to split off the username portion of the email addresses? This is quite simple using right and charindex. But I am still stumped at the rationale that 65535 is 1. Are there any other random associations like that?

Comment: I think the given task is out of my knowledge this is why I need your help. If anyone needs more information I am here to provide it. Thank you all!

Comment: No only the number 65535 is number 1. This is because there are more columns inside the table and for some reason number 1 would collide with another column.. I didn't make the database, I am a student that works on a copy of original database and the given task is superhard. Yes something like this, but this was made to remove email address from the domain "RIGHT(Domain, LEN(Domain) - CHARINDEX('@', Domain))"

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Ok I see thnx for the link

Comment: BTW I don't know why you had to rate down the question because of the mistake I made.. If I knew it earlier I wouldn't do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
Update [DB1 NAME]..DomainsActiV7
Set NumOfClicks = (
    Select SUM([DB2 NAME]..b.NumOfClicks)
        From [DB1 NAME]..DomainsActiV7 a
        Join [DB2 NAME]..ActiV7 b on a.Domain = RIGHT(b.Email, LEN(a.Domain))
)
```

And a second update to replace 65535 with 1

```
Update [DB1 NAME]..DomainsActiV7
Set NumOfClicks = 1
Where NumOfClicks = 65535
```

Comment: I included the @ to avoid issues like @ mail.com and @ civ.mail.com

Comment: See this link, in a case like that the civ.mail.com is a subdomain of mail.com, and unless specefied otherwise by OP should count as the same domain. http://www.domainsherpa.com/anatomy-of-a-domain-name-and-url/

Comment: Aron does your query count that 65535 is num 1.? how could I do that do you have any clues?

Comment: I'd use a second update just to replace 65535 with 1 after this one. Adding that to my answer now.

Comment: Is there any way to not ALTER the Database? That the conversion would happen in the query?

Comment: I'm not altering the database. I am updating the table values as per the conversion specified in the original question. If you need it to be all in one query, you can use a CASE statement to switch the value dynamicaly if it equals 65535. I don't have time to write that right now though, sorry.

Comment: Isn't update too late if data was aggregated in the prior step? I don't know why this needs to be done but here's the way to do it SUM(case when .NumOfClicks = 65535 then 1 else NumOfClicks end)

Comment: Use @KeithL 's comment here for the case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for Number of Clicks by domain?

```
select Domain,SUM(e.NumofClicks)
from D1..DomainsActiV7 d
   join D2..ActiV7 e
      on '@'+d.Domain = right(e.Email,len(d.domain)+1)
```

I have not tested this and only wrote it in answer, so it might need a little modification.

```
update D1..DomainsActiV7
set NumOfClicks = a.NumofClicks
from
D1..DomainsActiV7 d
join (
    select Domain,SUM(case when e.NumOfClicks = 65535 then 1 else e.NumOfClicks end) as NumOfClicks
    from D1..DomainsActiV7 d
       join D2..ActiV7 e
          on '@'+d.Domain = right(e.Email,len(d.domain)+1)
     ) a on a.Domain=d.domain
```

Comment: Yes this is correct. But I need to return combined clicks in the database 1 table.

Comment: you want to populate that column not just get the answer! You need to add an update to this query then

Comment: D1 and D2 should be changed to real names of Domains right? When I did that I got this error: "Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 42
Could not find server 'D*******' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers." I censored the name of database because the data in private, but yes the error is the imporant thing here. Do you maybe know how to fix?

Comment: D1 and D2 need to be changed to a database name assuming they are on same server.

Comment: I wrote the real names but the error I posted above showed up. Also does this query merge number 65535 as 1?

Comment: Converting 65535 to 1 has been added.