# Modifying an existing statement for SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database, email

I have 2 databases on the same server. We will call our first database `ActiDB` and the second one will be `DomiDB`. There is a table on `DomiDB` called `DomiActV7` which we will be working on. In `DomiActV7` there is a column called `Domain` and another column that is empty called `NumOfClicks`.

Now lets take a look at the other database called `ActiDB`. There are 2 tables there that are important to us. First table is called `ActV7` and the second one is called `SeV7`.

**What I need to do** is to get the `NumOfClicks` that is in the table `SeV7` (*Database* `ActiDB`) in the other database (`DomiDB`) combined together for each domain and stored in the empty column called `NumOfClicks`.

**Explaining upper text** "*Combined together for each domain*": There is a list of emails in `ActV7` and there is a list of domains in `DomiActV7`. Domain list should check `ActV7` emails and find matching domain (ex.: test@testdomain.com is our email and testdomain.com is our domain. The query found the email with same domain in that email and will now use that rows ID that will connect us to the other table in the same database called `SeV7`) The ID we can get from that row where the email with maching domain is, is called `SeV7OID`. With this ID we can get into the other table `SeV7` where we can find `NumOfClicks`.

Now that we found our way to `NumOfClicks` we need to somehow merge them together since there will be more emails with the same domain in previous tables which means that it will give us more IDs that will lead to more NumOfClicks.. I need to imput combined number of clicks back to the 1st table `DomiActV7`, also there is a specific number 65535 that should be treated as number 1. That is already implemented in the existing query tho.

The query that is made should be updated to look in `ActV7` for `Email` then get the `SeV7OID` ID and with that ID it should find the NumOfclicks and input them in the other database. I hope I didn't complicate things too hard but I'm trying to explain the situation as good as I can. Also here is a link to older post with a simillar question: [Link to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417543/connecting-column-from-one-database-with-multiple-columns-from-a-different-db-an)

Every Columns data type is varchar(50), only `SeV7OID` and other IDs are INT.

> *What is wrong with this query that it does direct Email search in `SeV7` which is wrong because there is more missing emails than there
>   is written in that table that is why we have to check from `ActV7`
>   which has all the emails stored.*
>
> **Existing query that needs to be modified:**
>
> `UPDATE DomiDB..DomiActV7  SET NumOfClicks = a.NumOfClicks  FROM
>   DomiDB..DomiActV7 d  JOIN (SELECT Domain, SUM(CASE WHEN e.NumOfClicks
>   = 65535 THEN 1 ELSE
>          e.NumOfClicks END) AS NumOfClicks  FROM DomiDB..DomiActV7 d  JOIN ActIDB..nact.SeV7 e  ON '@'+d.Domain =
>   right(e.Email,len(d.domain)+1))   a ON a.Domain=d.domain`

Example tables: *DomiActV7 from DomiDB*

```
+-----------------+-----------------+
|      Domain     |    NumOfClicks  |
+-----------------+-----------------+
|thisisadomain.net|                 |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| moreexamples.com|                 |
+-----------------+-----------------+
           ...............
```

*ActV7 from ActiDB*

```
+--------------------+-----------------+
|        Email       |  SeV7OID (key)  |
+--------------------+-----------------+
|example@examail.com |        1        |
+--------------------+-----------------+
|a@moreexamples.com  |        3        |
+--------------------+-----------------+
            .............
```

*SeV7 from ActiDB*

```
+--------------------+-----------------+
|    SeV7OID (key)   |    NumOfClicks  |
+--------------------+-----------------+
|          3         |       41        |
+--------------------+-----------------+
|          4         |       22        |
+--------------------+-----------------+
|          1         |      65535      |
+--------------------+-----------------+
          ..................
```

Comment: So from what I've gathered from your question, the problem is not getting information across different databases on the same instance (which works the same in most cases as getting information from tables all in one database). The issue is probably in your update logic. Descriptions are a little difficult to follow precisely, so it would help if you put sample data tables in your question.

Comment: Ok I will add them now! Hold on

Comment: What should value of NumOfClicks be if it's missing from table SeV7 but the email address is present in ActV7? That's the case you need to handle right?

Comment: It is never missing. It is either a number or 0. The numbers should be stacked up together for the same domain.

Comment: it should never be missing from output, but may be missing from input? Otherwise I'm not clear on what changes you need to existing query. Please see than answer that I posted and let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: No data is missing.. It was edited before so there is no nulls.. you can only find a 0 in the NumOfClicks in the SeV7 table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150800/discussion-between-xingzhou-liu-and-vissow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this produce expected result?

```
UPDATE d SET d.NumOfClicks = a.NumOfClicks  
FROM DomiDB..DomiActV7 d JOIN
( SELECT d.domain, 
    SUM(CASE 
      WHEN e.NumOfClicks = 65535 THEN 1 
     ELSE e.NumOfClicks END) AS NumOfClicks  
FROM
    DomiDB..DomiActV7 d1  
    JOIN ActIDB..Actv7 aa ON '@'+d1.domain = right(aa.Email,len(d1.domain)+1) 
    JOIN ActIDB..SeV7 e ON e.SeV7OID = aa.SeV7OID
     group by d1.domain 
)   a ON a.domain=d.domain
```

Comment: SeV7 also has an email column inside, the query i provided does a direct search for a match in SeV7 but that is wrong. It has to check ActV7 because there are all the emails (none missing) and then find the NumOfClicks over the ID that is connected from ActV7 to the SeV7

Comment: whoops, check now. I am assuming that DomActV7 is also updated and contains a complete list of domains.

Comment: Where should I run the query I get an error if I run it in ActiDB or DomiDB. Error if i run it in DomiDB: """"""""OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "ActiDB" returned message "Login timeout expired".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "ActiDB" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible".
Msg 53, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]."""""""""  Same goes for the other one just different DB name...

Comment: need to check your names. Are you copying directly or substituting object names? It shouldnt be interpreting ActiDB as a linked server unless you're giving it a 4 part name somewhere (so in your original query, ActIDB..nact.SeV7 would be interpreted as a 4 part name.). No  name should have more than 2 periods. You could try breaking the query down and selecting table by table to make sure they're accessible. I'm not aware of any other case that would cause that error besides something being specified as a 4 part name.

Comment: Yep that was the problem I modified the query and its okey. Now it has some problems with: ""The multi-part identifier "d.Domain" could not be bound.""

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150810/discussion-between-xingzhou-liu-and-vissow).

Comment: Check your substitutions. That error is a little bit tricky because it's not caused by the line where it happens (ie a.domain = d.domain) but rather occurs when theres a name problem in your definition for alias d. So check that "FROM DomiDB..DomiActV7 d JOIN ..." has the right names and that you're binding it to the alias "d".